# Downloading missing jar specified in pom.xml

Tags: maven

How to download **tomcat7-servlet-api.jar** that I was unable to download  with the following dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: [Maven Central doesn't have any artifact with that name](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22tomcat7-servlet-api%22). Where did you get this from? Are you trying to download from a different Maven repository?

Comment: I want to get tomcat7-servlet-api.jar  from any repository

Answer (score 0):

If you have tomcat installed, the servlet jar should be in the lib directory of the tomcat install. Although it will probably be much newer than 3.0

Comment: I need tomcat7-servlet-api.jar not servlet-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

You won't find the dependency with the group and artifact that you've specified. If you've copied the dependency annotation from a different project, check (and copy) the repositories in the pom.xml of that project.

As a side not, its appears that you need a tomcat7, servlet 3.0 API jar, and the equivalent in the central maven repo would be

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>7.0.57</version>
  </dependency>
```